# session expiry - Spring Session

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

How session expiry is handled in "Spring Session" ?
When a WebApp-B receives a request when the shared session (from WebApp-A) expires, how this scenario is handled ?

Do we have to redirect to WebApp-A for authentication ?

Comment: Does both application have implementation of AuthenticationEntryPoint? If the session expires, you can simply ask the user to login again using any of the webapp. Anyway they are sharing the same session store.

Comment: @qusyairi , It is mandatory to have authentrypoint in both the apps , isn't it ?

Comment: Well im asking just to confirm that both apps can handle authentication. To answer your question, the session expiry is handled just like a normal session. Spring session just have a wrapper around standard servlet session. So if you happen to delete the session in the store, user will automatically lost its session and logged out. If the session expires, user is also logged out from both webapp.  You can use any webapp for the user to authenticate and get new session. You can test this by adding nginx infront both webapp.